# Ruby / Geo - Find furthest points away from a given center

Tags: ruby, geolocation, geometry

Given a centre point, and a set of points, is there a gem / function that I can see which points are furthest away from origin, at a minimum distance away from each other?

```
def find_furthest origin, set, min_distance 
    #
end
```

## How I calculate distance, alternatives welcome

http://www.esawdust.com/blog/gps/files/HaversineFormulaInRuby.html

## origin

```
{"lat"=>43.643326, "lng"=>-79.3831843}
```

## Set

```
    [{"lat"=>43.64506, "lng"=>-79.384136},
     {"lat"=>43.642806, "lng"=>-79.380683},
     {"lat"=>43.645062, "lng"=>-79.384126},
     {"lat"=>43.644701, "lng"=>-79.384699},
     {"lat"=>43.644987, "lng"=>-79.383204},
     {"lat"=>43.64506, "lng"=>-79.384136},
     {"lat"=>43.644537, "lng"=>-79.385584},
     {"lat"=>43.643393, "lng"=>-79.380678},
     {"lat"=>43.642736, "lng"=>-79.381281},
     {"lat"=>43.642487, "lng"=>-79.382914},
     {"lat"=>43.642426, "lng"=>-79.383248},
     {"lat"=>43.642415, "lng"=>-79.383254},
     {"lat"=>43.645099, "lng"=>-79.383252},
     {"lat"=>43.642425, "lng"=>-79.383374},
     {"lat"=>43.64482, "lng"=>-79.385219},
     {"lat"=>43.64482, "lng"=>-79.385219},
     {"lat"=>43.645082, "lng"=>-79.38379},
     {"lat"=>43.64333, "lng"=>-79.380654},
     {"lat"=>43.644535, "lng"=>-79.385171},
     {"lat"=>43.64482, "lng"=>-79.385219}]
```

Comment: It's an array, sorry didn't realize there was a difference. I thought about inscribing a circle that's encompasses all points, then seeing which points are closest to the circle. But then I realized it's the same as seeing which points are furthest away from the center. Right now as a hack I'm seeing which points are the most NESW, and choosing them, but the solution feels incomplete somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you looking for a gem like this? https://rubygems.org/gems/geo-distance